# Unexpected POSIXct behavior for minutes

Tags: posixct

I do not understand why POSIXct returns NA for certain times? It does not make sense that for exactly that day, the function does not work.

```
> as.POSIXct("201003280501", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M", tz = "CET")
[1] "2010-03-28 05:01:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("201003280301", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M", tz = "CET")
[1] "2010-03-28 03:01:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("201003280201", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M", tz = "CET")
[1] NA
> as.POSIXct("201003290201", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M", tz = "CET")
[1] "2010-03-29 02:01:00 CEST"
```

Lubridate works

```
> lubridate::as_datetime("201003280201", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M", tz = "CET")
[1] "2010-03-28 02:01:00"
```

Any suggestions of what is going on?

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readr_1.1.1       rjson_0.2.20      odbc_1.1.6        DBI_1.0.0         data.table_1.11.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0      crayon_1.3.4    R6_2.3.0        pillar_1.3.0    rlang_0.3.0.1   rstudioapi_0.8  blob_1.1.1      tools_3.5.1     bit64_0.9-7    
[10] bit_1.1-14      hms_0.4.2       yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.5.1  pkgconfig_2.0.2 tibble_1.4.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that it is the day where you jump from winter time to summer time, thus the hour does not exist.